White window when minimizing a Brave browser window to the system tray in Windows 10
The issue: I use Autohotkey for years to minimize windows to the system tray, and to recover them later in my workflows.
Recently, I needed to test install JAWS Screenreader (trial). I needed it for a project, then uninstalled it again. Sidenote: The same day Brave browser updated.
Now I face the issue that when I minimize a browser window (or sometimes it happens with other windows too, but the browser I use the most), that the area of the browser/software window stays visible and turns completely white. As if you would cut it out.
I tried to find a solution but was not successful. Graphic card drivers were not changed. I suspect JAWS Screenreader to be the culprit having changed Windows 10 at the time of installation. Maybe it is even related to accessibility.
How can I find out what the reason could be?
And of course: How to fix the problem?

Note: I am using two screens (one connected to NVidia graphics card, one to Intel UHD 730), it happens on both screens.
Here is a recording showing the problem: https://gifyu.com/image/SBaqo (I could not upload the GIF here).

Update: I used the Task Manager and killed all processes one after the other. Indeed, when I killed all Brave browser processes, the white screen suddenly disappeared! ... So it must be some bug with Brave browser.
Posted as bug report over at https://community.brave.com/t/white-window-when-minimizing-a-brave-browser-window-to-the-system-tray-in-windows-10/575265

This appears to be a hold-over from JAWS -- apparently, during installation, it inserts hooks to access a window to read it aloud, and partial removal did not remove the hook.
One way to remove it more completely is to use the file, which might be at C:\Program Files\Freedom Scientific Installation Information\356DE2A8-01EB-464e-9C33-0EEA3F923000-18.0\UninstallJAWS.exe to complete the process. If it's gone, it might be easiest to reinstall Jaws (trial), then find UninstallJAWS.exe and run it as Administrator.
An alternative is to use an uninstaller application designed to thoroughly remove software. There are many free choices, so if one doesn't finish the job, try another.
As with any software, check the uninstaller at VirusTotal before use.
